# Can I set concurrentExecutionDisallowed and persistJobDataAfterExecution on Job instance?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to set concurrentExecutionDisallowed and persistJobDataAfterExecution on a single Job instance?

I am using Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE, Quartz 2.2.0, and JDK 1.8.0u05.

I created the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractAction extends Action implements Job
```

Where Action is a local POJO, and Job is the org.quartz.Job interface.

I then have a bunch of subclasses of AbstractAction which are defined in my spring context.xml as beans.

In my main method I grab the quartz scheduler from spring and load a DAO method to get a list of the AbstractAction beans to create my scheduled jobs, running code similar to this:

```
...
Scheduler scheduler = context.getBean("quartzScheduler", Scheduler.class);
...
for (...)
  ...
  AbstractAction jobBean = context.getBean(actionClass, AbstractAction.class);

  String jobKey = String.valueOf(actionId) + ":"
                + String.valueOf(actionClass) + "["
                + String.valueOf(actionParams) + "]@"
                + String.valueOf(cronExpression);

  JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder
    .newJob(jobBean.getClass())
    .withDescription(actionName)
    .withIdentity(jobKey, "scheduler")
    .build();

  JobDataMap jobDataMap = jobDetail.getJobDataMap();
  jobDataMap.put(...);
  ...

  Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .newTrigger()
    .withDescription("Trigger for " + actionName)
    .withIdentity(jobKey, "scheduler")
    .withSchedule( CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression) )
    .startNow()
    .build();

  try {
    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
  } catch (...) {...}
  ...
}
...
```

Basically, I can have multiple job instances of the same implementation class executing with different parameters (so different jobs and triggers, and that's fine. But, I don't want 1 job to execute again if it is still executing (same job and trigger).

Is there some property I can set in the Job or Trigger to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround that solved my issue. Because I stored my job params and cron expression in the job key, as well as the fact that I have access to my scheduler from Spring, I wrote this at the top of my AbstractAction class implementation of execute:

```
public abstract class AbstractAction extends Action implements Job {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

  protected abstract void preformAction(JobExecutionContext jobContext) throws TerminatingActionException;

  @Override
  public final void execute(JobExecutionContext jobContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    LOGGER.trace(...);
    Scheduler scheduler = context.getBean("quartzScheduler", Scheduler.class);

    try {
      List<JobExecutionContext> executingJobs = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
      for (JobExecutionContext executingJob : executingJobs) {
        Trigger executingJobTrigger = executingJob.getTrigger();
        Trigger currentJobTrigger = jobContext.getTrigger();
        JobDetail executingJobDetail = executingJob.getJobDetail();
        JobDetail currentJobDetail = jobContext.getJobDetail();
        JobKey executingJobKey = executingJob.getJobDetail().getKey();
        JobKey currentJobKey = jobContext.getJobDetail().getKey();
        String executingFireInstanceId = executingJob.getFireInstanceId();
        String currentFireInstanceId = jobContext.getFireInstanceId();
        if (executingJobTrigger.equals(currentJobTrigger) && executingJobDetail.equals(currentJobDetail) && executingJobKey.equals(currentJobKey) && !(executingFireInstanceId.equals(currentFireInstanceId))) {
          LOGGER.warn("Job " + String.valueOf(currentJobKey) + " is already executing, returning thread control.");
          return;
        }
      }
    } catch (SchedulerException schedulerException) {
      LOGGER.error("Encountered Scheduler Exception while trying to check existing jobs.", schedulerException);
    }
    ...
    try {
      ...
      preformAction(jobContext);
      ...
    } catch (...) {...}
    ...
  }
}
```

Hope this can help others out.

Thanks.